# How do I persist formdata from one component to another in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

All I had to use was @Input, @output, routing, activated route.

There are 2 components, namely `addbook` and `showbook`.
`addbook` component has a form with a submit button, which is supposed to save all the form data.

`showbook` component should just display the formdata.

These two components are placed in an a navbar of anchor tags. One is `addbook` anchor, which displays the form, and when you submit the form, it should persist the data (save it).

Finally, when you click on the show book anchor tag, it should display the formdata.

What I have come up with -
I've used a template driven form which when submitted invokes a

```
function { this.route.navigate(['showbook',bookID])}
```

Now I have imported the path as showbook/:id and component as showbook in routerModule.forRoot([routes]), in the `showbook` component, I have used activatedRoute to get the params, and using this, I have displayed the form data.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{path:'showbook/:id',component:showBookComponent}]) // in app module ts
```

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
this.bookId = params['id']
})
```

My code displays the formdata as soon as it is submitted, though the requirement is that I should save the data, and when `showbook` is clicked the formdata should be displayed.

I am not allowed to use local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `service` for this purpose.

1. After the form is filled up in `addbook` and saved, store the data in service.
2. When you navigate to `showbook`, retrieve the data from service.

Example:

**data.service.ts**

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  formData: Object;

  constructor() { }

  //assign the value
  setFormData(data){
    this.formData = data;
  }

  //To get the value
  getFormData(){
    return this.formData ;
  }
}
```

In **addbook.component.ts**

First import the service.

```
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
```

Inject the service in your constructor

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
```

On your save button function

```
this.dataService.setFormData(data);
```

In **showbook.component.ts**

First import the service.

```
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
```

Inject the service in your constructor

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
```

Display the form data on init function

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formData = this.dataService.getFormData();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I also figured out a way similar to this by using an array and i push the items into the array in a service and set and get data from it.!